# Azure Databricks empty Scala job always fails

Tags: azure-databricks

I have this very basic Scala class that I am trying to run as a job on Azure Databricks

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, Databricks!")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("Hello DAtabricks")
      .getOrCreate()

    try {} finally {
      spark.stop
    }
  }
}
```

My `build.sbt` looks like this

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.18"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.4.0" % Provided
)
```

I use `sbt assembly` to create an uberjar and  then I create a Job with one JAR task. Upload the JAR file and run the job. The job fails miserably and I am out of ideas on how to investigate what is going wrong.

This is the output from the job

- Log4j https://pastebin.com/TVq6jzQg
- Standard error https://pastebin.com/iZ1pRRTw

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you include Spark into the uberjar or it's marked as provided?

Comment: It is marked as provided. I've updated my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is embarrassing.
Because Databricks is a managed service, you get a spark session already configured for you and you are not supposed to close it.

This code works

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, Databricks!")

    /** See
      * https://docs.databricks.com/en/workflows/jobs/how-to/use-jars-in-workflows.html#recommendation-use-the-shared-sparkcontext
      */
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

    try {
      import spark.implicits._
      val ls = List("Hello", "Spark", "World")
      val ds = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(ls, 50).toDS
      ds.show()
    } finally {}
  }
}
```